# Green's Theorem and Line Integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametrization, line-integrals, greens-theorem

So I'm supposed to use Green' theorem to calculate the line integral

$$
\int_{C_1} \frac{x^2-1}{x^2+4y^2}dx +\frac{x}{x^2+4y^2}dy
$$

Where $C_1$ is the part of the parabola $y=1-x^2$ from point $(1,0)$ to $(-1,0)$

**My first problem:** I was able to calculate $\partial P/ \partial y$ and $\partial Q/ \partial x$ but it was indeed very tedious. Is there another way to calculate it? I thought about considering the derivatives only evaluated at the parabola, in a way I could write $x^2-1=-y$ but I don't know if I can do this because when we calculate the surface integral at Green's theorem we are considering the whole surface, right?

Anyways, I found out    $\partial Q/ \partial x - \partial P/ \partial y = 0$. Then, since the theorem requires me to have a closed path, I chose my "second path" as the ellipsis $x^2+4y^2=1$. So then I can write:

$$
\int_{C_1} \frac{x^2-1}{x^2+4y^2}dx +\frac{x}{x^2+4y^2}dy= -\int_{C_2} x^2-1dx +xdy
$$

After this we just need to parametrize the ellipsis as $y=\frac{1}{2} \sin(t); \enspace x=\cos(t)$.

Sadly enough **the answer I get is not the correct one** (which is $\pi/2$). What am I doing wrong/ is there a better way to proceed?

I appreciate any tips/corrections.

Comment: the two derivatives are not the equal

Comment: That vector field is not conservative. The trick is to say the integral of that vector field over the parabola is equivalent to the integral of a different vector field which is conservative. You get that different vector field by changing the numerator of $P$ to $-y$. Then you may close the loop with the *upper* half of that ellipse, not the *lower* half. (I'm just writing this as a reminder, you might have already done this but I can't tell because your second integral doesn't have limits)

Comment: I can't see how you got $\;Q_x-P_y=0\;$ ...In fact I get a rather ugly expression

Comment: Can also be solved without Green's theorem:
$$\int_{C_1} \boldsymbol F \cdot d\boldsymbol s =
\int_{C_1} \frac {(-y, x)} {x^2 + 4 y^2} \cdot d\boldsymbol s =
\frac 1 2 \arg(x + 2 i y) \bigg\rvert_{(x, y) = (1, 0)}^{(-1, 0)},$$
since, with a suitable choice of $\arg$, $\arg(x + 2 i y)/2$ is a potential for $(-y, x)/(x^2 + 4 y^2)$ in a region containing $C_1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that

$$\int_{C_1} \frac{x^2-1}{x^2+4y^2}dx + \frac{x}{x^2+4y^2}dy = \int_{C_1} \frac{-y}{x^2+4y^2}dx+\frac{x}{x^2+4y^2}dy$$

since on $C_1$ $y=1-x^2$. This new vector field is conservative on any region that doesn't contain the origin. To use Green's theorem, close the loop with the upper half of the ellipse $x^2+4y^2=1$ which means that

$$I = \int_{x^2+4y^2=1\:\cap\:y\geq 0} -ydx + xdy = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: clever ${}{}{}$

Comment: Thank you very much. The detail I was not understanding was the fact I could calculate the integral of the ellipsis on this new vector field which is conservative. I was using the initial vector field for the integral of the ellipsis.

Comment: After a long time, I was checking this problem again and I realised this would not work, since closing the loop  with the upper half of $$ x^2+4y^2=1$$ actually gives us 3 regions. I thought the intersection of the parabola and the elipse would occour only at $$y=0$$

Comment: @H44S It doesn't actually matter because the vector field is conservative on any region that doesn't enclose the origin. Any minus signs due to a flip in orientation don't matter because the double integrals are all $0$

Comment: But my curve is no longer a simple closed curve (It has intersections) so I'm not sure green theorem holds

Comment: @H44S What my comment was implying is that you have three simple closed curves. You can orient them and add each of them with each other, like a system of integral equations. Or the other way of looking at it is that conservative vector fields don't care about intersections or what have you, they are path independent.